# Connection from pentaho to mysql

Tags: database-connection, mysql-connector

I'm having problem with the connection between Pentaho and Mysql. I started the Pentaho Server and then i launch the workbench of the psw pentaho client. To connect i'm using the jdbc connctor latest version: `mysql-connector-java-8.0.11.jar`. 
When i try to connect to mysql instance (that is running) i get the following error:

```
Errore di connessione al database [database] :   
 org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleDatabaseException: 
  Error occurred while trying to connect to the database

  La classe di driver 'org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver' non è stata trovata,
  assicurarsi che il driver 'MySQL' (file jar) sia installato.
   org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver


  org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleDatabaseException: 
  Error occurred while trying to connect to the database

  La classe di driver 'org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver' non è stata trovata,    
  assicurarsi che il driver 'MySQL' (file jar) sia installato.
  org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver
  ...

Nome dell'host: 127.0.0.1
Porta:3306 
Nome database: schema
```

Comment: Solved. I put the `mysql-connector-java-5.1.42-bin.jar` file in the `lib` directory!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly , check whether the your pentaho version supports mysql connector .
if it supports then problem is mysql plugin,open spoon.bat

> **Open Tool menu -> Marketplace ->install mysql plugin  after installing restart pentaho and try again .**

Hope it will solve the issue .